# How do I clean dust between my desk and glass protecting it?

Tags: cleaning

I have a huge sheet of protective glass on top of wood desk with a computer set up on top of that. Dust has collected between desk top and glass. How can I get the dust out without disassembling and removing all the computer stuff?

Comment: If it ain't busted, don't fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how thick the glass is. If the pane is thick enough, you can lift one end a bit and slide some shims underneath, then repeat on the other side until you have a gap big enough to clean between.
**But** the glass needs to be really thick for this to work. As an example: I have some glass shelves in my cupboard. These are 80x30 cm and 6 mm thick, and are specified for a maximum allowable weight of 10 kg. A desktop computer with monitor is easily twice that, and the pane of glass is much larger. As a first approach, double the size = half the carrying capacity, so if your desk is 150 x 80, you'd need a glass pane several cm thick to carry your computer. This is unlikely, so you'll have to remove the computer before lifting the glass.

Normally the weight of the computer isn't an issue: the entire area of the glass is supported by the desk. But if you lift the glass, it's supported only by the edges.

Answer (score 1):

If the glass is up off the wood at all, sometimes there are small rubber bumpers around the edges to keep it off the wood, then get compressed air and blow between the glass and wood.

You could try it even if it isn't raised up as it might still have a small gap to let you blow it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do,

1. take a piece of cloth,
2. take a spoon, the cloth covers the back of the spoon,
3. insert the back of the spoon as you are cleaning the space between the glass top and the desk.

IN CASE THE AREA OF THE GLASS AND THE DESK IS TOO BIG:

1. with the back of the spoon with very long (not big in area) cloth, use the back of the spoon in such a way that it comes off the other end, then slide it gently with the right hand and then with the left hand (in a harmonic motion) until you get the whole under glass top cleansed.

Comment: does that work when there's a computer sitting on the glass plate?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use compressed air and blow it under the glass covering.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you would perform this task?

Comment: Take a can of compressed air that comes with a straw and attach it. The straw may be thin enough to get under the glass covering and blow the dust out. Not sure why my answer got down voted.

Comment: You were probably down voted because your answer didn't contain more information. Please edit your answer to include what you put in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just around the edge of the glass I take a thin credit card and put a clorox wipe around it and slide it around the edges.